# Come up with a search algorithm to search within documents

Tags: python, algorithm, search, pattern-matching, computer-science

I was working on a project where I need to search within all the documents(pdf/docs etc)  present in the database relevant to any query.
I earlier used a simple relation where I stored relevant keywords associated with a document and if the query contains those keywords then I fetch those documents. But this method is not so reliable as those keywords might be misleading. I need to search within the documents and I am looking for a practical search algorithm that can scale well and has less time complexity.
Any suggestions and resources are most welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Your question is too vagueness, but I know Apache Lucene is a great searching library, you may check it out and find the algorithm that it's using.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb, sir what part confused you, please I don't want to use a library, I want to implement algorithm by myself.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why I said "find the algorithm that it's using", it's using great algorithms but I think you need to have some data science backgrounds because their not simple for everyone.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb , yeah ok i got that part wrong. sorry. Thanks

Comment: The canonical solution is to create an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index): an index of all words and the documents in which they appear. So if you search for "steam train", it intersects the set of documents that contain the word "steam" with the set of documents that contain the word "train," and that's your result. There are, of course, extensions that let you search for phrases, and rank the results on relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Rabin-Karp](https://github.com/pardeepdgr/bite-of-programming/blob/master/Searching/rabin_karp/RabinKarpSubstringSearch.java) (based on hashcode) search algorithm. As you have to search more than one pattern in many documents, it will get the hashcode of all patterns and will look for all patterns in one go.

Comment: That gets pretty expensive if you're repeatedly searching a very large number of documents. Just file I/O time when you're searching a million documents will be excessive. For a large number of documents you'll want to preprocess the data to build some kind of index.